# SQL developer export cuts data in cell short when exporting WKT

Tags: json, csv, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, wkt

I'm using pl sql and sql developer (mac). I'm trying to export a sdo geometry by converting it to WKT (using `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY`). The problem is that when use the export function in sql (right clicking the query result then clicking export) if I export the result as either a json or csv. The text that describes the WKT is cut short.

I believe this is a problem with the export function and not the data as when I copy the data from the cell to my clipboard and paste it, it looks fine.

The export function maxes out at 4000 characters and the desired string is 9707 characters long.

Is there any way to fix this export issue?

Comment: How are you converting to WKT - what data type does it end up as, and how long are the entries? If you're using [sdo_util.to_wktgeometry](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_util.htm#SPATL1251) that returns a CLOB. Maybe you can add an example of the original and truncated data to the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've updated the question. The example is too long, but essentially it is cutting the CLOB at 4000 characters when using export

Comment: Yeah, [only 4k is supported for most export types](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/04/sql-developer-preferences-for-delimited-text-exports/#comment-29983), including CSV. XML should work but that doesn't really help you. Would writing to a file on the server work for you, or does it have to be on the client? Or can you copy-and-paste from a worksheet; or use SQL\*Plus? Depends if it's a one-off or regular task, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this I've exported the file as an XML from SQL Developer (right click query result and click export).

To turn the XML into a CSV I then ran the following python script

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd

    tree = ET.parse('query_output.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    output = []
    for row in root.findall('ROW'):
        insert = {}
        for element in row:
            result = element.attrib['NAME']  ### Column Name
            insert[result] = element.text  ### Data
        output.append(insert)

    result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output)
    result.to_csv('query_output.csv', index = False)
```